# How to mention analysis tools/functions developed during a thesis

Tags: thesis, tools

I am just about to finish my Master thesis. During the analysis, I wrote two functions which simplify certain tasks and put them into a R package. Furthermore, I extended an existing R package by parallelizing it.

While these actions do not have any value for the scientific outcome of my thesis and just simplified my analysis by saving me time, I wonder if I should mention these tasks within my thesis?

If yes, in which section? My idea was to put it in a section in the discussion called something like "additional outcomes of this work" and link to the specific packages on my Github account. However, as the package I wrote is not yet published to the public and the package I parallelized is not yet updated, I question myself if I have enough "serious stuff to mention".

If not, what are the reasons for not mentioning such results in a scientific work? If I would be the supervisor, I would like to know about such outcomes of a thesis although they just affect the technical analysis part.

Answer (score 1):

If one-sentence descriptions would be enough for another researcher to replicate your work, you owe the reader nothing more. I would only link to a code repository if it were both topical and substantial (and if it were, that code might be a major theme of the paper).